# Deletion of multiple Login Ip range associated with a profile in a single go?

Tags: administration

How can we delete multiple Login Ip range associated with a profile in a single go?

Answer (score 0):

We can use force.com IDE for this.Just need to extract profiles and from xml file need to remove the login ip ranges associated with profile and the just save to the server.

Comment: This does not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy a profile xml (that currently has ip ranges) without the  tag, it will count as you're not modifying ip ranges at all.
You can remove all ip ranges but one on the xml to let Salesforce know that you are editing that section, then remove the last one from the frontend.